# Unable to print with CUPS

Tags: printing, cups

I'm trying to setup a CUPS server on the rpi. I have a Brother HL1110 (USB connected) and installed the ARM driver as per instructions here https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_rp2.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&comple=on&redirect=on Print works fine using `lpr` but not over a network via CUPS. The `/var/log/cups/error_log` looks like the following:

```
...
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@orangepilite"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.2.7"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[14]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[19]="LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/BrGenPrintML2.ppd"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=usb://Brother/HL-1110%20series?serial=H6N434263"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=BrGenPrintML2"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[26]="PRINTER=BrGenPrintML2"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-pdf"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertopwg (PID 26655)
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertopdf (PID 26656)
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 26657)
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/brother_lpdwrapper_BrGenPrintML2 (PID 26658)
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb (PID 26659)
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] PID 26655 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertopwg) exited with no errors.
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] OUTFORMAT=\"(null)\", output format will be PDF
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Color Manager: Calibration Mode/Off
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-BrGenPrintML2)
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Failed to send: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Failed to get find device cups-BrGenPrintML2
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Loading USB quirks from \"/usr/share/cups/usb\".
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Loaded 88 quirks.
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Printing on printer with URI: usb://Brother/HL-1110%20series?serial=H6N434263
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] pdftopdf: Last filter determined by the PPD: brother_lpdwrapper_BrGenPrintML2; FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE: application/vnd.cups-pdf => pdftopdf will not log pages in page_log.
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] PID 26656 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertopdf) stopped with status 1.
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] PID 26657 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] libusb_get_device_list=6
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Printer found with device ID: MFG:Brother;CMD:PJL,HBP;MDL:HL-1110 series;CLS:PRINTER;CID:Brother Laser Type3; Device URI: usb://Brother/HL-1110%20series?serial=H6N434263
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Device protocol: 2
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Sending data to printer.
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] **** Error: Too many pages in Page tree.
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] No pages will be processed (FirstPage > LastPage).
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Read 680 bytes of print data...
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Wrote 680 bytes of print data...
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Sent 680 bytes...
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] PID 26658 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/brother_lpdwrapper_BrGenPrintML2) exited with no errors.
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] Waiting for read thread to exit...
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] PID 26659 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] End of messages
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] printer-state=3(idle)
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] printer-state-message="Sending data to printer."
D [29/Oct/2019:22:11:13 +1000] [Job 33] printer-state-reasons=none
```

All of these are debug messages and the only warnings I get are the following:

```
W [29/Oct/2019:02:18:04 +1000] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
W [29/Oct/2019:02:18:04 +1000] CreateDevice failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Is `org.freedesktop.ColorManager` critical to getting CUPS to work? Does anyone know how to get it fixed?

UPDATE: With `colord` installed, I get the following output:

```
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] OUTFORMAT=\"(null)\", output format will be PDF
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] Color Manager: Calibration Mode/Off
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-BrGenPrintML2)
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_BrGenPrintML2
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device.Get(ProfilingInhibitors)
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] PID 1719 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertopdf) stopped with status 1.
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] PID 1720 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] **** Error: Too many pages in Page tree.
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] No pages will be processed (FirstPage > LastPage).
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] Read 680 bytes of print data...
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] Wrote 680 bytes of print data...
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] Sent 680 bytes...
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] PID 1721 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/brother_lpdwrapper_BrGenPrintML2) exited with no errors.
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] Waiting for read thread to exit...
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] PID 1722 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] End of messages
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] printer-state=3(idle)
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] printer-state-message="Filter failed"
D [09/Feb/2020:17:45:51 +1000] [Job 60] printer-state-reasons=none
```

Comment: The ColorManager mentioned in the logs is probably provided by the systemd `colord.service`. It's required because it manages the color profiles of devices such as cameras and printers. It looks like the `colord.service` somehow fails to do its job (maybe check `systemctl status colord`). Assuming that the network connection itself is not the problem, another potential problem might be authentication issues (see for example, this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417906/authentication-is-required-to-create-a-color-profile)).

Comment: @yesno Right. I've installed `colord` now, but I'm still getting the "Too many pages in Page tree" error. Please see update.